# How to extract data from Finnhub.io? (importing JSON to pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am a beginner in any code language.

I want to model and explore data from stock markets, so I tried importing from finnhub, as they suggest.

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/candle?symbol=QQQ&resolution=1&from=1572651390&to=1572910590&token=bq1q5g')
print(r.json())
```

I can't seem to be able to work with it.

```
#Manipulation dict to list
type(r.json())
QQQ = str(r.json())
type(QQQ)
QQQ_1 = json.loads(QQQ)
```

This message happens:
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes. So reading other posts I tried this code, but it won't work.

```
QQQ.replace("\'", "\"")
```

I just want to build a simple dataframe... I tried json_normalize, but I have to do a pd.series on it to split it. There must be a simple way.

TIA!

My code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

#Import data
import requests
import json
r = requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/candle?symbol=QQQ&resolution=1&from=1572651390&to=1572910590&token=bq1qmlfrh5rd509cok5g')
print(r.json())

Out[248]: {'c': [198.89, 198.89, 198.8, 198.79, 198.84, 199.55, 199.62, 199.62, 199.63, 199.62, 199.6, 199.67, 199.66, 199.7, 199.78, 199.77, 199.76, 199.77, 199.8, 199.77, 199.75, 199.79, 199.74, 199.77, 199.75, 199.74, 199.76, 199.78, 199.75, 199.75, 199.75, 199.76, 199.75, 199.75, 199.74, 199.75, 199.8, 199.9, 199.85, 199.89, 199.92, 200, 199.95, 200, 200.01, 200.12, 200.1, 200.11, 200.14, 200.09, 200.05, 200.06, 200.06, 200.04, 200.02, 200.01,......etc

#Manipulation dict to list
type(r.json())
QQQ = str(r.json())
type(QQQ)

Out[249]: str

QQQ_1 = json.loads(QQQ)

Out[250]:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-250-ba3a93b0612e>", line 1, in <module>
    QQQ_1 = json.loads(QQQ)

  File "C:\Users\Poste\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\Poste\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\Poste\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes


#Replacing quotes with double quotes
QQQ.replace("\'", "\"")

Out[251]: '{"c": [198.89, 198.89, ......etc

QQQ_1 = json.loads(QQQ)
Out[252]:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-252-ba3a93b0612e>", line 1, in <module>
    QQQ_1 = json.loads(QQQ)

  File "C:\Users\Poste\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\Poste\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\Poste\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you share the output of your code.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it.

```
QQQdf = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
```